# Conformal map is an isometry

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I have the upper half-plane $\mathbb H$ with the metric given by $$\mathrm ds^2=\frac{1}{y^2} (\mathrm dx^2+\mathrm dy^2)$$ and the unit disk $\mathbb D$ with the metric given by $$\mathrm ds^2=\frac{1}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}(\mathrm dx^2+\mathrm dy^2)$$
I found that, considering the complex plane, there is a conformal map $W$ that takes $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb D$, which is \begin{eqnarray*}
W\colon\mathbb{C} & \to & \mathbb{C}\\
z & \mapsto & \frac{z-\mathrm{i}}{z+\mathrm{i}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now I have to see that $W$ is an isometry, but I don't know how to relate the two concepts.
My teacher gave me a hint about finding the holomorphic derivative, but I don't know how it helps.
If I compute the derivative, I get $$\frac{\mathrm d W }{\mathrm d z}= \frac{2\mathrm i}{(z+\mathrm i )^2}$$
And I see that it never nullifies, but I don't know if this is useful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given a metric
$$ds_z:={|dz|\over y}\qquad(z\in H)$$
and a metric
$$ds_w:={|dw|\over 1-|w|^2}\qquad(w\in D)\ .$$
In addition a map
$$W: \quad H\to D, \qquad z\mapsto w:= {z-i\over z+i}$$
is considered. One computes
$$1-|w|^2=1-w\bar w={(z+i)(\bar z-i)-(z-i)(\bar z+i)\over|z+i|^2}={-2i(z-\bar z)\over|z+i|^2}$$
and
$$W'(z)={2i\over(z+i)^2}\ .$$
It follows that
$$ds_w={1\over1-|w|^2}\bigl|W'(z)\bigr|\>|dz|={|z+i|^2\over4y}{2\over|z+i|^2}|dz|={1\over2}ds_z\ .$$
This means that the map $W$ halves then length of all curves, hence, strictly speaking, it is not an isometry.

Comment: But as H and D have the same constant gaussian curvature (-1), then they must be locally isometric. And I thought this was the only map that takes H to D.

Comment: There are two different normalizations in use, one with $\kappa=-1$, the other with $\kappa=-4$. See here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_metric